# Установка параметров при открытии Spinner и Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Есть спискок Spinner, при отметке элемента списка заполняется Edittext (значениями по умолчанию для элемента списка)
Использую setOnItemSelectedListener в onItemSelected

При открытии в OnCreateView обновляю отметку из переданных параметров: ставлю адаптер открываю и отмечаю элемент списка setSelection(). Jбновляется Edittext все верно.

Но затем мне нужно изменить значение EditText. setText идет после setSelection(). Но вызов setOnItemSelectedListener  идет после выполнения всех команд. И значение затирается.Подскажите как исправить?

```
     spAbonType.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    spAbonType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

         // **ОБНОВЛЯЮ ЗДЕСЬ EDITTEXT**
         edt.setetxt("10");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    // устанавливаем параметры
    bundlePersons = getArguments();
    spAbonType.setSelection(i);
    edt.settext("5");
```